# Results From A JSON Call to Variable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to get a ID from a JSON call, and not sure what the issue is. I have a Callback function set up to set a global variable as such.

**GOAL:** *Make a call to a DB, get the ID from the results returning.*

**STEP 1 - Make call to JSON and Parse Results**

```
 callAjaxGet(<set url>,function(myReturn){

            var noteID = ''

            $.each(myReturn.results, function(i, note){
                noteID = JSON.parse(note.id);
            });
    })
```

**STEP 2 - JSON/Callback Function**

```
function callAjaxGet(url, callBack){

$.ajax({

    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data,textStatus,xhr){
        return callBack(xhr);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){

        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

**STEP 3 - The Returning JSON**

```
{
"next": "http://selleck.beta.org/playlist/notes/?limit=20&offset=20&play=437",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 258,
        "url": "/playlist/notes/258/",
        "content": "testing",
        "play": 437
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter what I'm doing, the `noteID` comes back without value. I've looked in Google Development Tools, XHR, and can see the JSON coming back, so thinking I've misunderstood something.

Thank you for any thoughts and suggestions

Steve

Comment: Where is your `callback` function defined? Also, the server returns the data in the `data` parameter of the `success` callback.

Comment: You are returning xhr. Shouldn't  you be returning data?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Two things were wrong.

1. Was using XHR instead of Data
2. Wasn't parsing the JSON properly, the ID is in an array, so had to set the first entry, so

   noteID = myReturn.**results[0]**.id;

Thanks A.Sharma and ron tornambe for the pointer on the XHR error

Steve